# PDF file corrupted when I sign with keypair

Tags: pdf, key, signature, private-key, public-key

I am using this code to generate a eletronic signature with a public key and a private key, but the pdf is getting corrupted after the signature, could you guys give me some help?

Thanks in advance.

```
let keyPair;
let pdfDoc;
let publicKey;

// Load PDF document
document.getElementById("pdfFileInput").addEventListener("change", () => {
  const file = document.getElementById("pdfFileInput").files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: arrayBuffer })
      .promise
      .then((doc) => {
        pdfDoc = doc;
        document.getElementById("generateKeyPairBtn").disabled = false;
        console.log("PDF document loaded:", pdfDoc);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});

// Generate key pair
document.getElementById("generateKeyPairBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
      modulusLength: 2048,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
    },
    true,
    ["sign", "verify"]
  )
  .then((kp) => {
    keyPair = kp;
    publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
    console.log("Key pair generated:", keyPair);
    console.log("Public key:", publicKey);
    document.getElementById("signBtn").disabled = false;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});

// Sign document
document.getElementById("signBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!pdfDoc) {
    console.error("No PDF document loaded");
    return;
  }
  
  pdfDoc.getData()
    .then((pdfUint8Array) => {
      window.crypto.subtle.sign(
        {
          name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        },
        keyPair.privateKey,
        pdfUint8Array
      )
      .then((signature) => {
        const signedPdf = new Uint8Array(signature);
        console.log(signedPdf)
        const blob = new Blob([signedPdf], { type: "application/pdf" });
        const downloadLink = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
        downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.download = "signed.pdf";
        downloadLink.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("verificationResult").innerText = "Document signed!";
        console.log("PDF document signed and saved as blob:", blob);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

I've tried to break the pdf file in chunks to see if fix the problem but still the same. It does not give me any error when it generates the file, just when I try to open it, the error appears, I am very sorry about my bad English, if you guys need some more information, let me know.